# Is it possible to define parametrized type aliases in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

The C# documentation recommends the `using` directive to bring types into local scope. Indeed, I can do something like:

```
using DD = IDictionary<string,IDictionary<string,Blah>>;
```

and it works fine. However, I would like to be able to do:

```
using DD<Blah> = IDictionary<string,IDictionary<string,Blah>>
```

But the compiler dies at:

```
using DD<Blah...
        ^ ; expected
```

Is there a way to express such a type synonym, instead of repeating horrendously long generic names all over the place ?

**Context**

I wanted to know if it was possible to write a generic, recursive wrapper on the output type of read-only collection. With the following interface

```
interface IIndexable<in In, out Out> { Out this[In idx] { get; }}
```

I managed to write

```
IIndexable<Key,VOut> map(IIndexable<Key,VIn> coll, Func<VIn, VOut> f)
```

I guess I'm really trying to emulate the convenience of Haskell's `Functor` typeclass.

So, wrapping my complex type in a custom class will not cut it, as it is being assembled from a stack of `map()`s and there is no single `new` call to replace with a custom wrapper class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, no. You'd have to define an alias for each `Blah` type (in your example).

Like:

```
using DB = IDictionary<string,IDictionary<string,Blah>>;
using DG = IDictionary<string,IDictionary<string,Gah>>;
```

I know, kinda frustrating.

(**However**, I would encourage you to consider whether you *really* want code that's dealing with variables typed as `IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, Blah>>` in the first place. When you're nesting data structures like that, it's a good time to ask yourself whether you should be encapsulating some of that in a custom class that actually makes it easy to do what you want without giving yourself a headache. Of course, it may be that you're asking this question specifically *because* you're writing such a class, in which case, carry on.)

Comment: Thanks. I'll expand the question to provide more context on what I'm trying to achieve, perhaps it will clarify !

Answer (score 3):

It would be better to introduce your own type for `IDictionary<string, Blah>` at least for the sake of readability.

The simplest `class MyDic : Dictionary<string, Blah> {}` will go. And you are free of aliases and long names. Just `IDictionary<string, MyDic>`.

If to answer to your question exactly. No, C# requires you to fully qualify your aliases.

Comment: Upping the answer since it was almost simultaneous to the one above, thanks!

Comment: Thanks :) P.S. In fact my answer was 3 seconds faster :D